# Parsing exactly n parameters in antlr4

Tags: python, python-3.x, grammar, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 with a python3 runtime. In the language I am try to parse, there are numerous operations (around 50) that accept a fixed number of parameters in the form `OPNAME [ parameter1, parameter2, parameter3 ]`

I used to have a grammar with a rule like this:

```
statement: OP1 '[' NUM ']'
    | OP2 '[' NUM ',' NUM ']'
    | OP3 '[' NUM ',' NUM ',' NUM ']'
    | OP2or3 (('[' NUM ',' NUM ']')|('[' NUM ',' NUM ',' NUM ']'))
    ;
```

However, for more clarity, I decided to make a subrule `parameter[n]` that accepts exactly `n` parameters. Hence, my (full example) grammar looks like this:

```
grammar test;

program: (statement? NEWLINE)* EOF;

statement: OP1 parameter[1]
    | OP2 parameter[2]
    | OP3 parameter[3]
    | OP2or3 (parameter[2]|parameter[3])
    ;

parameter[n]
locals[i = 1]
    : '[' NUM 
        ( ',' NUM {$i += 1} )*
      ']' 
      {$i == $n}?
    ;



OP1     : 'OP1'     ;
OP2     : 'OP2'     ;
OP3     : 'OP3'     ;
OP2or3  : 'OP2or3'  ;

NUM     : ('0'..'9')+;
NEWLINE : '\n'      ;
WS      : [ \t\r] -> channel(1);
```

Running this grammar on the following `testfile.txt` almost works. I tested having more or less parameters in OP1, OP2 and OP3, and if I don't have exactly the corresponding number of parameters, that fails. **However, that does not work for OP2or3, which always fails for 3 parameters**. I guess antlr parser tries to check first with 2 parameters, fails predicate, and then fails to backtrack correctly (error message is `Error at [5:16] : rule parameter failed predicate: {$i == $n}?`). Content of `testfile.txt` :

```
OP1 [1] 
OP2 [32, 52]
OP3 [1, 2, 3]
OP2or3 [1, 2]
OP2or3 [1, 2, 3]
```

I tried to replace with a more explicit rule with predicate at entrance, but that still does not work (error message is `Error at [5:7] : no viable alternative at input '['`)

```
parameter[n]
    : {$n == 1}? '[' NUM ']'
    | {$n == 2}? '[' NUM ',' NUM ']'
    | {$n == 3}? '[' NUM ',' NUM ',' NUM ']'
    ;
```

For information, here is the python code I use to test my grammar:

```
import codecs
from antlr4 import *
from antlr4.error.ErrorListener import ErrorListener
from testParser import testParser as Parser
from testLexer import testLexer as Lexer

class SimpleErrorThrower(ErrorListener):
    def syntaxError(self, recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, column, msg, e):
        msg = msg.replace('\n', '\\n')
        raise RuntimeError("Error at [%s:%s] : %s" % (line, column, msg))

def load_code(filename):
    return codecs.decode(open(filename, 'rb').read(), 'utf-8')

def ParseFromRule(input_string, rule_to_call='program'):
    '''Try to parse a given string (case insensitive) from a given rule.
        Raises 'AttrivuteError' if rule does not exist.
        Raises 'ParsingException' if parsing failed.
        Returns the parse tree if parsing was successfull.'''
    source = InputStream(input_string)
    lexer = Lexer(source)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = Parser(stream)
    parser.removeErrorListeners()
    parser.addErrorListener(SimpleErrorThrower())
    parseTree = getattr(parser, rule_to_call)()
    return parseTree


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    args = ArgumentParser()
    args.add_argument("-p", "--print", help="Print resulting tree.", action='store_true')
    args.add_argument("filename", metavar="Source filename", help="file containing the code to test.", type=str)
    options = args.parse_args()

    input_string = load_code(options.filename)
    try:
        tree = ParseFromRule(input_string, 'program')
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(str(e))
        exit(1)

    if options.print:
        print(tree.toStringTree(recog=tree.parser))
```

And here is my `Makefile`:

```
ANTLR_CP=/usr/local/bin/antlr-4.5.1-complete.jar
ANTLR=java -Xmx500M -cp "$(ANTLR_CP):$$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool

all: testParser.py

clean:
    rm -f *Lexer.py *Listener.py *Parser.py *.tokens *.pyc

testParser.py: *.g4
    $(ANTLR) -Dlanguage=Python3 test.g4
```

**Do you have any idea if I could make a rule `parameter[n]` that will also work for `OP2or3` ?** Having that subrule really helps with clarity, on a rule that tends to change quite often (some operators are added or removed every few months)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sorry to have bothered anyone looking at my question, but I found an answer myself, using python magic. Maybe that can help someone someday. I reworked `parameter[n]` to take as input either an `int` or a `tuple`:

```
parameter[n]
locals[i = 1]
    : '[' NUM
        ( ',' NUM {$i += 1} )*
      ']'
      {($i == $n or $i in $n)}?
    ;
```

Note the parenthesis in the semantic predicate. **You need to put thoses parentheses** as it will be translated as `not (i == n or i in n)` in the python parser, and without the parentheses that will not be negated correctly (I guess that could be viewed as an antlr4 bug.)

Hence, now my statement rule is :

```
statement: OP1 parameter[1]
    | OP2 parameter[2]
    | OP3 parameter[3]
    | OP2or3 parameter[(2, 3)]
    ;
```

and that work on my testfile:

```
$ python3 test_grammar.py testfile.txt -p
(program (statement OP1 (parameter [ 1 ]))
(statement OP2 (parameter [ 32 , 52 ]))
(statement OP3 (parameter [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]))
(statement OP2or3 (parameter [ 1 , 2 ]))
(statement OP2or3 (parameter [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]))
<EOF>)
```